# python asyncore or threadpool for web crawler?

Tags: python, web-crawler

It seem what i can do fast crawler with python in two ways:

1. thread pool with block sockets
2. non block sockets select,asyncore,etc..

i thnk where is no real need in thread here, and solution #2 better.

which is better and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is usually preferred to asyncore. It is an asynchronous I/O framework that [can also work with thread pools](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html).

In Python, you should prefer asynchronous IO to threads, simply because [threads are a second class citizen in its canonical implementation (CPython)](http://dabeaz.blogspot.com/2010/01/python-gil-visualized.html) due to GIL.

Comment: I am intrested in implementation on low level at this moment, how twisted do it internaly with asyncore?

Comment: @Evg Twisted and asyncore are two different implementations, they are not related.

Comment: i understand) i mean what twisted internally can do it only by threads or asyncore at low level, i am right? And my question what better threads with blocking sockets or asyncore.

Comment: or as you say "Twisted and asyncore are two different implementations" how twisted do it internaly? i mean python interface to non blocking sockets at low level used by twisted.

Comment: @Evg seems from the source it uses `select` module, which uses platform-specific polling mechanism (epoll, kqueue, etc).

Comment: thanx for you help, i edit question according to you, what do you think about prefered solution #1 or #2?